# List iteration & setting values with Java 8 Streams API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to understand how to use the Java 8 Streams API.

For example, I have these two classes:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}

public class UserWithAge {
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    private int age;
    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
}
```

I have a `List<User>` of ten users, and I want to convert this to a `List<UserWithAge>` of ten users with the same names and with a constant age (say, 27). How can I do that using the Java 8 Streams API (without loops, and without modifying the above classes)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `map()` feature of the stream to convert each `User` instance in your list to a `UserWithAge` instance.

```
List<User> userList = ... // your list

List<UserWithAge> usersWithAgeList = userList.stream()
        .map(user -> {
                // create UserWithAge instance and copy user name
                UserWithAge userWithAge = new UserWithAge();
                userWithAge.setName(user.getName());
                userWithAge.setAge(27);
                return userWithAge;
         })
         .collect(Collectors.toList()); // return the UserWithAge's as a list
```

Answer (score 2):

While you could do this, You should not do like this.

```
List<UserWithAge> userWithAgeList = new ArrayList<UserWithAge>();

userList.stream().forEach(user -> {
                UserWithAge userWithAge = new UserWithAge();
                userWithAge.setName(user.getName());
                userWithAge.setAge(27);
                userWithAgeList.add(userWithAge);
});
```

Comment: Does `userWithAgeList` have to be `final`?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz variables used within stream operations should be final or effectively final otherwise issues may arise. (consider parallel use of the stream by separate threads)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ListIteratorExp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setName("foo");

        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setName("bee");

        list.add(p1);
        list.add(p2);

        list.stream().forEach(p -> {
            String name = p.getName();
            System.out.println(name);
        });
    }

}
```

```
class Person{
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

```
output:-
vishal
thakur
```